# I'm not getting a "preview" of my answers on math.se (main), but am able to do so on meta?

Tags: support, markdown-preview

As the title states, for 2 + days I'm not receiving any preview of my answers, prior to posting, and at times, I am unable to view the original post while answering a question on math.se main. However, I am I able to preview my answers and the OP while answering on meta math.se.

This has led to the need for me to post answers (with typos, missing $'s) that I would otherwise have fixed prior to posting, leading to the need for me to post, check, edit, post, check, edit...

Is it my browser?

Have others had any trouble recently?

Comment: @WillHunting I'm using Firefox... I don't know why I continue to have problems with viewing my answers prior to posting.  It seems particularly problematic when I have written long answers, and editing such long answers often freezes up my browser, perhaps because of the rendering of scripts?

Comment: @WillHunting Hi, btw $\quad$ 8-)

Comment: I am having the same problem in Safari, but it seems to work in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the trouble. Problem fixed. I cleared my browser's cache, etc. and tested: Everything is good now!

amwhy

---

*UPDATE*

Still having trouble (or, that is, I'm having trouble again). It (not being able to view my rendered answers while answering) seems only to affect my open tab for math.se, not the open tab (webpage) for meta.math.se. (Everything is displaying fine as I type this). Simultaneously open, on firefox.

I tried Asaf's suggestion, but that doesn't seem to help. I'll keep trying :-(

Comment: Usually a Ctrl+F5 will clear things up and fix the problem.

Comment: @Asaf. Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. It's been driving me crazy: Not seeing what I'm doing!